# what is the benefit of using a BroadcastReceiver in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

This might be a foolish question for you, Please consider that im not an expert in Android programming.

I had implemented a PhonestateListener with an inline code in my Service.But after following the broadcast tutorial from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).I saw the same phoneStatelistener is explained with the help of a BroadcastReceiver.Can anyone pls explain me the benefits?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Broadcast receiver wakes your application up, the *inline code* works only when your application is running.

For example if you want your application to be notified of an incoming call, even if your app is not running, you use a broadcast receiver.

If your application is playing audio, and you want to stop the music on an incoming call, you use the *inline code*.

Comment: Thats a simple , but good explanation.So ... its better to use a Broadcast Receiver for such purposes, because broadcast Receiver s can invoke the apps! :)

Answer (score 2):

A broadcast receiver also called as receiver is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android run time once this event happens. Broadcast receiver is also called the gateway between your application and outside world.

example of broadcast receiver is when new sms arrives, broadcast receiver sends notification to messaging app and small icon pops up in notification bar.

rules of broadcast receiver:
it has maximum limit of 10secs,
do not do any asynchronous  operations which may take more time,
do not do heavy database operations  or networking operations in broadcast receiver.